# Loading only part of a file into an Image

Tags: java

**[Java]** I'm using Images / BufferedImages (I don't currently know a better way) to load external pictures unto the canvas.

**Q:** Is there a possibility of loading / displaying only a part of the picture? For example, using only a 60x60 area from a larger 500x300 picture file. (I believe this is called a Sprite) Loading the file using ImageIO.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BufferedImage input = ImageIO.read(new File(inputFile));
BufferedImage output = new BufferedImage(60, 60,  BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB)
Graphics g = output .getGraphics();
g.drawImage(input, 0, 0, null); //adjust 0, 0 to some x, y if necessary
ImageIO.write(output, "png", new File(outputFile));
```

Comment: How would I go about 'adding' the resulting Graphics object to the Graphics2D object I currently use on my 'render()' method?

Comment: @Acidic try `Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;` According to [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getGraphics()) getGraphice() - `This method returns a Graphics2D, but is here for backwards compatibility.`

Comment: I think my problem was in understanding that - `output.getGraphics()` passes a reference, rather than a value. Everything is working fine now, thank you.